# Young adult book about teenagers in highschool with superpowers

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I read it in the late 90s to the early 21st century. The main character was a teenage girl who could turn invisible, I think her powers manifested while waiting for a counselor when someone approaches her and she wishes she wasn't seen. One of her friends was a black girl who could grow taller.

Main character is sitting in a building or a bus wishing she couldn't be seen and finding people/a person walking past her to realize she can turn invisible. Her black girl friend grew taller (and possibly her limbs grew as well) during a basketball game at school.

Comment: A few additional thoughts might help locate this book. Cover art is good. The time you read this book or when you think it was published. Are people with these powers common at all or is this the first time the main girl learns people can have powers for real? Is the school the main setting or something else? Does someone fill the role of antagonist or is this more a coming of age, girl vs. herself book?

Comment: Only certain kids in the story get powers so not common. First time they get them. School is the main setting. The cover would have the title on it so not sure why I would have that.

Comment: @myztikrice: I think that they are asking whether you remember anything about the cover art. While it is not easy to search for e.g., "a kind of blue cover which I think had a girl looking into her locker while a bright light shines out of it", but it helps us identify a book while searching if we see a cover that matches.

Comment: It may also help if you could tell the approximate year when you first met this book, how old the book seemed like, and the language you read this in.

Comment: Late 90s early 00s, recent, English

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, there's a deleted answer that obliquely suggested [*Michael Vey: The Prisoner of Cell 25*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Vey:_The_Prisoner_of_Cell_25), but it looks like it only matches on being set in a high school where people have powers.

Answer (score 1):

I need to do more research, but one possibility is the [*Goddess of the Night*](http://allreaders.com/book-review-summary/goddess-of-the-night-30563) book, first of the *Daughters of the Moon* series. The main character, Vanessa, has the ability to become invisible (and later float), but only when she's feeling strong emotions. Her best friend is a time traveler and she later meets two other girls, one of which has the power of premonition and another the power of telekinesis. I have not yet found any mention of someone growing taller, but the first girl she meets with powers after Catty (the time traveller) is a Serena Killingsworth with unexplained powers of darkness that include reading minds.

[image]

I have requested the book from my local library. A quick readthrough of the first chapter suggests that this is not a match after all, as her power got triggered during a nightmare as a child:

> That had been the night she woke from a nightmare and couldn't see her body in the pale glow of the night-light. She had been terrified and afraid to tell her mother. She had thought she had done something bad. Her mother had heard her crying and ran into her room. She had lifted her arms to be comforted, but her mother couldn't see her. That had frightened her even more. While her mother was searching the house for her, her molecules had come back together, but they had come back wrong. Her face had looked different. She had locked herself in the bathroom then, know her mother could never love her now. Sleep had finally taken her, and when she woke in the morning back in her own bed, she had looked normal.

Also, basketball is only mentioned in the context of a description of the gym.

Comment: Nah nothing about a timetraveling friend. Just kids in a highschool.